# How to rebase commits **into** the current branch (and not on top of another branch)

Tags: git

I’m initially on the branch `oldstable`, and I would like to backport all commits from master into it

```
          A---B---C oldstable <- HEAD
         /
    D---E---F---G master
```

What I want:

```
          A---B---C---F’---G’ oldstable <- HEAD
         /
    D---E---F---G master
```

I did read the documentation of git rebase but without a lot success. Ideally, I would like something like `git rebase --into-this-branch master` or `git rebase oldstable..master oldstable`, where the commits in `master` but not in the current branch (`oldstable`) would be rebased into it.

I found a few ways to do it, but neither are very ergonomic if I put them in a script.

---

```
git switch --detach master   # or `git checkout --detach master` if you prefer
git rebase oldstable
git branch --force oldstable # manually move the commit pointed by oldstable
git switch oldstable         # or `git checkout topic` if you prefer
```

The issue here is that if the rebase need manual intervention (e.g. a there is a merge conflict), then I will no longer be on `oldstable` when the rebase is done, of if I abort it with `git rebase --abort`.

---

I also tried:

```
git cherry-pick $(git log --reverse --pretty="%H" oldstable..master)
```

The issue with that one is that if there is a merge conflict, `git status` isn’t useful at all to understand what commit was just cherry-pickeded, which one failed and what still need to be done (like when using `git rebase`). It also doesn’t automatically ignore commits that where already cherry-picked into oldstable.

---

and I tried:

```
# we assume that there all modifications are commited or stashed
current_commit="$(git rev-parse oldstable)"
git reset --hard master
git rebase ${current_commit}
```

The main issue with that one is that `git rebase --abort` will leave `oldstable` pointing to the same commit as `master` instead of resetting it to `C`.

---

EDIT:

- Why not merge?

Because the real use-case is to backport only some of the commits that are in `master` but not yet in `oldstable`. A more precise, but more complex example would be to rebase `H` and `I` into oldstable, which is just a variation of `git rebase --onto oldstable master~2 master`, but where I want to move `oldstable` and not `master`.

```
          A---B---C oldstable <- HEAD
         /
    D---E---F---G---H---I master
```

- Are you looking for `git cherry-pick F G`?

That’s exactly what `git cherry-pick $(git log --reverse --pretty="%H" oldstable..master)` does (see above for more details).

- Why do you care if you land on oldstable after the rebase or not?

Short answer. Because the `git rebase` is going to be hidden into a script. I could just detach `HEAD` before doing the rebase, as shown in the first try, but I don’t want to leave the repo in a messy state if there are rebase conflicts. If I was the only user of that script it would not be an issue at all, but the idea is to make it possible to use that script to my less experienced git colleagues. And I do think that they may forget to do a `git switch -C oldstable` when finished, and be confused by the state of the repo.

Long answer. What I’m doing is that I want to backport only some commits from `master` into `oldstable`. What I am concretely doing is to rebase commits from `master` into `oldstable` except for a list of commit to exclude. That list of commit is stored into a text file. From that list, I generate a sub-script that will filter them from a list of commits (using sed). I then set `$EDITOR` to point to that sub-script during an interactive rebase (`env EDITOR=that/sub/script.sh git rebase --interactive oldstable master`). And the whole process is wrapped into a `backport.sh` script that me or my colleagues will use. This works perfectly, except that the wrong branch is moved during the rebase / `oldstable` isn’t moved / other issues presented above.

---

EDIT (partial solution, very cursed):

I realize that it should be possible to do what I want (in a very cursed way) by doing

```
git switch --detach master
git rebase --interactive oldstable
# add those commands at the end of the todolist
# exec echo 'refs/heads/oldstable' > .git/rebase-merge/head-name
# exec echo 'full-40-characters-hash-of-commit-C' > .git/rebase-merge/orig-head
```

This will modify the branch being checkouted automatically by git rebase when the process finishes.

I did not post it as an answer because the git repository may not be in `.git`, for example if you do use `git workspace` and I did not find (yet) a way to automate the edition of `.git/rebase-merge/git-rebase-todo` so this partial answer is not really usable as-it, and probably way too hacky to be considered valid.

Comment: Why not just merge `master` into `oldstable`?

Comment: are you looking for `git cherry-pick F G` ?

Comment: It might help to explain why you don't want to simply merge. Normally it's odd to purposefully rewrite a commit that is already on a long lived shared branch such as `master`.

Comment: I don't understand your issue with the rebase you provided. Why do you care if you land on `oldstable` after the rebase or not, since you already know how to point the branch to that commit? (And note you get there in a single command too with `git switch -C oldstable` ) And as for abort, if you aren't on the branch you can just switch back to it.

Comment: Rebase _is_ cherry pick. Your picture diagram is a textbook picture of cherry pick. If you don't like what happens when there's a merge conflict, too bad. Merge conflicts are very likely with rebase / cherry pick.

Comment: (Rebase also moves the branch pointer. That's the only difference.)

Answer (score 0):

If your issue is only about moving the wrong branch name :

- you can create a temporary branch for the duration of the rebate:

  `git checkout -B wip/rebase/master master`

  and rebase that branch
- or mention a commit sha rather than a branch name:

  `git rebase oldstable $(git rev-parse master)`

Once the rebase is completed, you can update your `oldmaster` branch to that commit:

```
git checkout oldstable

git merge --ff-only wip/rebase/master
# or
git merge --ff-only <resulting sha>
```